# Migrate Centos AWS image to Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We have the AWS centos system and we have our software installed on it. Now we want to move this EC2 instance to Azure. What is the process and best way approach that we can follow.
Any Document or article will help.

Answer (score 0):

Azure has a guide for this specifically

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/migrate-tutorial-aws-azure